# Draw or edit a freeform shape in Outlook message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, screenshot, shapes

I'm trying to add a circle to a screenshot that I added to an email message in Outlook.

How do I do this in the message editor without using any external photo editing utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may click Insert > Shapes, select Oval then hold on Shift to draw a circle on the screenshot:[image]

Afterwards, you may use the drawing tools to change the format of the circle, for example, a red one with no fill:

[image]

Comment: Just to note that to get to the screen shot above the message has to be in its own pop up window and not in outlook's preview pane.

Answer (score 3):

Paste the screenshot into MS Paint and add a circle from there. The Snipping Tool included with Windows 10 makes taking and editing screenshots easy, if you need to do this often.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. "without using any external photo editing utilities?"

Comment: The original question was edited to include the line you quoted after I answered it. OP, why can't you use external tools?

Comment: I'd like to stay in the current environment. I would prefer to use what Outlook has available. I think of it in the same way that I am able to format text within the editor instead of needing to use MS Word or some other program to make the change. Does this help?